# Getter function to retrieve a 2d array element when the 2d array is a data member of a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, multidimensional-array, generic-programming

I have a 2d array which is a data member of a class.  I initialized it to `false`.

It is in its own .cpp class file.

Format is:

```
//constructor
genericClassName::genericClassName(bool)
{

bool genericArray [3][3] = 
{
    { false, false, false },
    { false, false, false },
    { false, false, false },
};
```

From my main method I have used a getter function in the following format:

```
//creation of an object of the class
genericClassName objectName;

//console output
std::cout << objectName.getterFunction (1, 1) << std::endl;
```

The numbers in the `()` are the arguments passed to the `getterFunction` to represent the subscripts of the 2d array.  Row and column in that order.

The getterFunction definition in the class .cpp file is in the following format:

```
bool genericClassName::getterFunction (int row, int column)
{
    return genericArray[row][column];
}
```

The function is not returning `0`.  Instead I get a three digit number.  I am uncertain if the function call is wrong, the initialization of the array is wrong, or the definition of the getter is wrong.  Is the definition creating a local array which is not the array initialized to false?

The getter is public.  The array is private.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to see where the problem could be. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is `genericArray` a local variable in your constructor? If so, you cannot access it from outside the constructor. It might also be hiding a class member with the same name (that stays uninitialized).

Answer (score 1):

You have mainly two problems:

**Problem - 1:** You have declared an array inside your constructor, which make not initialize your class member. Therefore, when you use your `getterFunction()`, you are accessing uninitialized array element, which gives some garbage values.

**Problem - 2:** You have mentioned a parameterized constructor here,

```
//constructor
genericClassName::genericClassName(bool)
{ .... }                          ^^^^^^
```

and created the instance without passing a parameter

```
//creation of an object of the class
genericClassName objectName;           // this need a default constructor
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If this was all your code, I don't think that, the code will compile as you have not defined any `default constructor` in your code.

---

The non-generic way of fixing is as follows: [SEE HERE](https://www.ideone.com/gzkU1c)

```
class genericClassName
{
private:
   bool genericArray [3][3];  // this has be defined here/ not generic anymore
public:
   genericClassName()
   {
      for (auto &row : genericArray)
         for (auto& ele: row)
            ele = false;
   }
   genericClassName(bool trueOrfalse)  
   {
      for (auto &row : genericArray)
         for (auto& ele: row)
            ele = trueOrfalse;
   }
.............
.............
```

---

In order to make the 2D array generic, you can use `std::vector`. That will look like as follows:

[SEE LIVE HERE](https://www.ideone.com/XDgEnU)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using Type2D = std::vector< std::vector<bool> >;

class genericClassName
{
private:
   Type2D genericArray;
public:
   genericClassName()  // defualt constrctor with some random size
      :genericArray(3, std::vector<bool>(3, false))
      {}
   genericClassName(bool trueOrfalse, int size)  // use initilizer list here
      :genericArray(size, std::vector<bool>(size, trueOrfalse))
      {}


   bool getterFunction (int row, int column)
   {   return genericArray[row][column];     }

   // just to print all elements
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const genericClassName& obj);
 };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const genericClassName& obj)
{
   for (const auto &row : obj.genericArray)
      for (const auto& ele: row)
         out << ele << " ";
   return out;
}
 int main(void)
 {
   genericClassName objectName2;  // works with default constrctor
   std::cout << objectName2.getterFunction(1, 1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << objectName2 << std::endl;

   genericClassName objectName(true, 4); // specify the size of your 2D array as well
   std::cout << objectName.getterFunction(1, 1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << objectName << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.
   The problem is with assigning bool values to 2 dim array at constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class genericClassName{
    bool genericArray [3][3];
    public:
            genericClassName()
            {
                    int i, j;
                    for( i=0;i<3;i++)
                            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                                    genericArray[i][i] = false;
            }
            bool getterFunction (int row, int column)
            {
                return genericArray[row][column];
            }
 };

 int
 main(void)
 {
    genericClassName objectName;

    cout << objectName.getterFunction (1, 1) << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```